# How to squeeze the characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to squeez the characters, for this I write the code but my regular expression did not worked
python code is:

```
file1 = open("C:/Python26/Normalized.txt");
normal = re.compile(r'(.)(\1+)')
f1=open("rzlt.txt",'w')
contents1=file1.read();
tokens1 = nltk.word_tokenize(contents1)                    
for t in tokens1:
    t = re.sub(normal,r'\1',t)
    f1.write(t+"\n")
f1.close()
```

my file is like

```
AA-0
A-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaa-aaaaaa
AA-aaaaa-A
aaaaa-A-aaaa
AAA-0-aaaa-aaaaaaaa-aaaaaa
AAA-0
AAA-0-aaaaaaaa
AAA-0
aaaaaaaa
```

**Desired output is**

```
A-0
A-a-a
a-a
a-a
A-a-A
......
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: If the file has something like 'aabb-c', what's the output? Is it 'a-c' or 'ab-c'?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
normal = re.compile(r'(.)(\1+)')
with open("Normalized.txt") as file1:
    with open("rzlt.txt", 'w') as f1:
        for line in file1:
            f1.write(normal.sub(r'\1', line))
```

This produces the output:

```
A-0
A-a-a
a-a
a-a
A-a-A
a-A-a
A-0-a-a-a
A-0
A-0-a
A-0
a
```

#### Notes

To open files, `with` statements are used.  This assures that the files are subsequently closed.

Answer (score 0):

theres no need to use regular expressions for this purpose, the most common way of eliminating duplicates is to turn the collection into a set. but, as Shashank has commented, for the input format you're dealing with even that is not necessary:

```
for line in file:
  newline = '-'.join(x[0] for x in line.split('-'))
```

Comment: If the file format really is as above, then a set is not even necessary. Just grab the first character on each substring of the split list.